# Window 10 freezes when open any browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, windows-10, browser

Few days back I got issue with all browsers. Whenever I open any browser window fully freezes. But when I close browser it works normal. I tried with safemode but problem still there. Only Microsoft Edge working fine. Please help

Comment: Did you install new browser plug-ins/add-ons recently?

Comment: No. Plugin or addon

Comment: Freezes means that you cannot start or switch to other programs (e.g. those minimized on the Taskbar) than the browser? The mouse can be moved normally, you can close the browser normally? Does this also occur when your browser start page is set to a blank page (`about:blank`)? Does it also occur when your network and internet connections are disconnected?

Comment: Yes i cannot switch to another program. Yes i can close browser. It close normali. I tried with internet connection off. But problem still there.

Answer (score -1):

First off, please update your question with your system specs. You can right click the windows icon and click "System" to view them. Secondly, please expand on your post (i.e. define "All Browsers").

Some things you can try: (If a step doesn't solve it, move on to the next step)

1) You can try clearing your browser cache and cookies with [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)

2) Reinstall your browser.

3) Open command prompt as admin (right click windows icon) and type `sfc /scannow` (NOTE: Let this finish completely. It will take some time)

4) Open command prompt as admin again and type `chkdsk /r`. It will ask you if you want to check the volume the next time the system starts. Type <kbd>Y</kbd> and hit enter, then restart your computer (It is *extremely* important that this process is not interrupted)

5) After all these, if you're still having issues, download and run [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/thankyou/), as this could be some virus/adware affecting your desktop browsers (seeing that Microsoft edge is working fine)

Comment: Exactly. If the first two steps do not work, it is a problem with the system, not the browsers. @Ramhound

Comment: Now, back to the system commands. I have run across many corrupt computers where the desktop browsers freeze, or all desktop apps cannot connect to the internet. However, windows apps like IE 10 and Microsoft Edge would connect fine. These are the general steps I start with when repairing computers like this.

Comment: All Browsers means chrome, firefox, IE, Safari. And I already tried all first 4 points. For 5 point i have macfee full licenced. I scans system there is no malware or virus.

Comment: K something else to check is right click the windows button and check "Programs and Features". You can sort by date installed, and check for any suspicious programs.

Comment: Nothing no new software